# fastlookups vs record lookup in flows (Visual Workflows)

Tags: flow, visual-workflow

Can someone please explain what is the difference between fast lookup and  record lookup in flows. 
When should we be using fast lookups and when should we use record lookups.

I have tried to find documentation around this topic but found it to be very minimal also we have faced issues when we used fastlookups ( didn't work as expected) and changing them to record lookup works.

Answer (score 1):

Fast lookups are more powerful, primarily due to a few key features that are not available in record lookups

- [cross object field references](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_crossobject_reference_simple.htm)
- the ability to store multiple records in a [sObject collection variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_resources_sobject_collection.htm)

Furthermore, fast lookups can simplify your flow because you can store all fields in a single sObject variable, instead of having to create a new flow variable for each data point to be stored.

I once came across a scenario on success where John Stevens found a way that a record lookup could do something a fast lookup could not, but now i cant recall what it was.  I'll update this if / when i find that.

Answer (score 0):

A **Record element** is always going to be ONE record that you are processing.  If you want the ability to process ONE OR MULTIPLE records you must use a **Fast element**.

**Fast elements** grab ALL of the field values from one sObject variable.  This means you can’t use regular variables or other flow resources (like screen fields), while a **Record element** captures ONLY the fields that you want.

Comment: Some of this is not correct.  A fast lookup only includes the fields you specify.   Fast lookups can work perfectly well with screen elements, though if you are working with multiple records in a collection then you will need to use a loop or another construct.  Fast lookups let you do cross object field references, which can be very helpful.  There are likely others, I'll add an answer in the future.

Comment: @gorav if you added an answer, I'd give you a vote, esp if you could find some documentation. I'm a bit unclear on these components myself.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and compile something.  I know there is change in the wind as they work on the new flow builder as flash will soon be history.  I've seen some contemplating around these two options...will be interesting to see how it plays out.